# How to get AdvancedSubtensor on GPU

Tags: gpgpu, theano, theano-cuda

I have some subtensor and for some reason, Theano cannot transfer it to the GPU.

Some sample code:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.printing
import theano.compile.io
import theano.compile.function_module
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops import as_cuda_ndarray_variable

n_copies, n_cells = 5, 10
P = T.constant(numpy.zeros((n_copies, n_cells), dtype="int32"))  # (n_copies,n_cells) -> list of indices

meminkey = T.fmatrix()  # (batch,n_cells)
meminkey = as_cuda_ndarray_variable(meminkey)
i_t = T.ones((meminkey.shape[0],))
batches = T.arange(0, i_t.shape[0]).dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x')  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
P_bc = P.dimshuffle('x', 0, 1)  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
meminkeyP = meminkey[batches, P_bc]  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
meminkeyP = as_cuda_ndarray_variable(meminkeyP)

func = theano.function(inputs=[meminkey], outputs=[meminkeyP])
theano.printing.debugprint(func)
```

I added some `as_cuda_ndarray_variable` to make the problem more clear because in the output, you see the transfers `GpuFromHost` and `HostFromGpu`, which it would avoid if it could do the AdvancedSubtensor on GPU. Output.

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN (CNMeM is disabled, CuDNN not available)
GpuFromHost [id A] ''   5
 |AdvancedSubtensor [id B] ''   4
   |HostFromGpu [id C] ''   1
   | |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [id D]
   |InplaceDimShuffle{0,x,x} [id E] ''   3
   | |ARange{dtype='int64'} [id F] ''   2
   |   |TensorConstant{0} [id G]
   |   |Shape_i{0} [id H] ''   0
   |   | |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [id D]
   |   |TensorConstant{1} [id I]
   |TensorConstant{[[[4 0 1 2..5 8 9 7]]]} [id J]
```

So, why is Theano not able to transform this into a GPU op?

Also, how can I rewrite the code that Theano will do the calculation on GPU?

---

Related question in Google Groups: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/theano-users/renshaw%7Csort:date/theano-users/SKipmABM6aY/7mPEanvGxwAJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/theano-users/Advanced$20index$20on$20GPU/theano-users/pukE6_tGnd8/-mnM2Q1NZ5cJ)
and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/y8XxgYouYSs).

Comment: @talonmies: This is about the CUDA backend of Theano.

Comment: Indeed it is. But this is still a question about Theano and not about CUDA programming. They are not the same thing. If you have some actual CUDA kernel code or CUDA APIs calls you would like help with, by all means add them in the question and retag it. But I suspect you don't and therefore this question shouldn't be tagged with the CUDA tag

Comment: @talonmies: I guess you are right. I am not sure what tag to use to say that my question is only specific for the CUDA backend of Theano. gpgpu is probably also not the correct one.

Comment: I understand completely the problem about tagging. In this case the CUDA tag is really a "meta tag" - you are programming in something that uses CUDA under the hood, but your question isn't really about CUDA, even if CUDA and the GPU is indirectly involved. One solution might be to have a dedicated tag for the GPU backend of Theano, if there were enough questions like this to warrant it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so in the Google Groups posts which I linked, it's pretty good explained why it doesn't work. AdvancedSubtensor is the most generic form which works with all crazy types of indexing variants. Then there is AdvancedSubtensor1, which only works for a certain kind of subset. There only exists a GPU version for AdvancedSubtensor1, not for AdvancedSubtensor. I didn't fully understand the reason but there is an ongoing discussion about it.

AdvancedSubtensor1 can be used when there is a single list of indices. However, in my example, that is not the case. The common workaround you see, also in some other example in those Google Groups post, is to flatten the array first and calculate the indices for the flattened array.

Most examples work with some kind of `nonzero()` or so, where you also would flatten the base arguments in the same and then you get the indices for the flattened version.

So, the question is, how to apply this to my code?

Actually, there is a simpler solution where it will use AdvancedSubtensor1 which I didn't realized initially:

```
meminkeyP = meminkey[:, P]  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
```

However, before I realized that, I came up with a generic solution which also works for other cases. I transform my indices tuple `(batches, P_bc)` into indices for the flattened version. This is done with this function:

```
def indices_in_flatten_array(ndim, shape, *args):
  """
  We expect that all args can be broadcasted together.
  So, if we have some array A with ndim&shape as given,
  A[args] would give us a subtensor.
  We return the indices so that A[args].flatten()
  and A.flatten()[indices] are the same.
  """
  assert ndim > 0
  assert len(args) == ndim
  indices_per_axis = [args[i] for i in range(ndim)]
  for i in range(ndim):
    for j in range(i + 1, ndim):
      indices_per_axis[i] *= shape[j]
  indices = indices_per_axis[0]
  for i in range(1, ndim):
    indices += indices_per_axis[i]
  return indices
```

Then, I use it like this:

```
meminkeyP = meminkey.flatten()[indices_in_flatten_array(meminkey.ndim, meminkey.shape, batches, P_bc)]
```

This seems to work.

And I get this output:

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN (CNMeM is disabled, CuDNN not available)
GpuReshape{3} [id A] ''   11
 |GpuAdvancedSubtensor1 [id B] ''   10
 | |GpuReshape{1} [id C] ''   2
 | | |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [id D]
 | | |TensorConstant{(1,) of -1} [id E]
 | |Reshape{1} [id F] ''   9
 |   |Elemwise{second,no_inplace} [id G] ''   8
 |   | |TensorConstant{(1, 5, 10) of 0} [id H]
 |   | |Elemwise{Mul}[(0, 0)] [id I] ''   7
 |   |   |InplaceDimShuffle{0,x,x} [id J] ''   6
 |   |   | |ARange{dtype='int64'} [id K] ''   4
 |   |   |   |TensorConstant{0} [id L]
 |   |   |   |Shape_i{0} [id M] ''   0
 |   |   |   | |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [id D]
 |   |   |   |TensorConstant{1} [id N]
 |   |   |InplaceDimShuffle{x,x,x} [id O] ''   5
 |   |     |Shape_i{1} [id P] ''   1
 |   |       |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [id D]
 |   |TensorConstant{(1,) of -1} [id E]
 |MakeVector{dtype='int64'} [id Q] ''   3
   |Shape_i{0} [id M] ''   0
   |TensorConstant{5} [id R]
   |TensorConstant{10} [id S]
```

Small test case:

```
def test_indices_in_flatten_array():
  n_copies, n_cells = 5, 4
  n_complex_cells = n_cells / 2
  n_batch = 3
  static_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
  def make_permut():
    p = numpy.zeros((n_copies, n_cells), dtype="int32")
    for i in range(n_copies):
      p[i, :n_complex_cells] = static_rng.permutation(n_complex_cells)
      # Same permutation for imaginary part.
      p[i, n_complex_cells:] = p[i, :n_complex_cells] + n_complex_cells
    return T.constant(p)
  P = make_permut()  # (n_copies,n_cells) -> list of indices

  meminkey = T.as_tensor_variable(static_rng.rand(n_batch, n_cells).astype("float32"))
  i_t = T.ones((meminkey.shape[0],))  # (batch,)
  n_batch = i_t.shape[0]
  batches = T.arange(0, n_batch).dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x')  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
  P_bc = P.dimshuffle('x', 0, 1)  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
  meminkeyP1 = meminkey[batches, P_bc]  # (batch,n_copies,n_cells)
  meminkeyP2 = meminkey.flatten()[indices_in_flatten_array(meminkey.ndim, meminkey.shape, batches, P_bc)]

  numpy.testing.assert_allclose(meminkeyP1.eval(), meminkeyP2.eval())
```